# validate date from react datepicker using yup

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'm having this issue on how can I validate the date coming from the DatePicker using yup.

Yup Schema

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  projectName: yup.string().required('Please enter project name here'),
  projectClientId: yup
    .string()
    .required('Please choose your client for this project'),
  startDate: yup
    .date()
    .transform((value) => {
      return value ? moment(value).toDate() : value;
    })
    .min(new Date(), 'Later date not allowed'),
});

<DatePicker
                        id='startDate'
                        selected={projectInfo.startDate}
                        ref={register}
                        onChange={(date) => handleOnStartDate(date)}
                        className={`w-full px-4 py-4 relative ${
                          errors.startDate
                            ? 'border-danger focus:border-danger'
                            : 'border focus:border-primary'
                        } border rounded-md focus:border-primary focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline`}
                      />
```

Comment: Where does the `DatePicker` component come from? What kind of data should be validated? What result do you expect?

Comment: I'm using react-datepicker, I just want to validate if the user click a date that is already past it will display an error